# Using python to simulate 2D elastic collisions

Tags: python, cocos2d-iphone, physics

I have wrote a script in Python 3 to simulate elastic collisions in two dimensions.
I don't know what I am doing wrong because when I run it, the balls seem to stick to each other and sometimes glitch to become one ball. Also, when a single ball hits any edge of the screen, it will bounce off, however when when another ball is stuck to it, it will cause one of them to come off the screen.

[Eqautions that I used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtl13.png)

Snippet of the code:

```
class Particle(Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image):
        super(Particle, self).__init__(image)
        self.Vxi, self.Vyi = random.randint(-3, 3), random.randint(-3, 3)
        self.mass = random.randint(1, 100) / 1000

        self.schedule_interval(self.update, 1/60)

    def update(self, dt):
        self.xpos, self.ypos = self.position

        if self.xpos <= self.width/2 or self.xpos >= scr_width - self.width/2:
            self.Vxi *= -1
        if self.ypos <= self.width/2 or self.ypos >= scr_height - self.height/2:
            self.Vyi *= -1

        for particle in director.scene.children[0][1].particles:
            particle_xpos, particle_ypos = particle.position

            if abs(self.xpos - particle_xpos) <= self.width/2 + particle.width/2:
                if abs(self.ypos - particle_ypos) <= self.height/2 + particle.height/2:
                    xmomentum = (particle.mass * particle.Vxi) + (self.mass * self.Vxi)
                    ymomentum = (particle.mass * particle.Vyi) + (self.mass * self.Vyi)
                    Vxf = (xmomentum - particle.mass * (self.Vxi - particle.Vxi)) / (particle.mass + self.mass)
                    Vyf = (ymomentum - particle.mass * (self.Vyi - particle.Vyi)) / (particle.mass + self.mass)
                    self.Vxi = Vxf
                    self.Vyi = Vyf

        self.xpos += self.Vxi
        self.ypos += self.Vyi
        self.position = self.xpos, self.ypos
```

Comment: where are you defining ```scr_width``` and ```scr_height```?

Comment: It is unclear if this is a physics related question or a coding problem.  If its physics question, this is probably not the place to get an answer as this forum is focused coding issues.

Comment: It's a coding related question, and the scr_width and scr_height are defined as 640 and 480 respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot to update the other particle's velocity upon collision.

Before

```
self.Vxi = Vxf
self.Vyi = Vyf
```

there should also be

```
particle.Vxi = Vxf + (self.Vxi - particle.Vxi)
particle.Vyi = Vyf + (self.Vyi - particle.Vyi)
```

Style wise, I think the variables can be named better. A Particle object shouldn't have an attribute called `Vxi` or `Vxf`. As far as the physical particle is concerned it only has one velocity. The concept of initial/final velocities is associated with the numerical simulation, which the attributes of the Particle class shouldn't model. In your current code, the "final" velocities of `self` is updated as its initial velocity, which can be confusing.

The initial velocity (`Vxi`, `Vyi`) should be taken from `self.Vx` and `self.Vy` at the beginning of `update`. At the very end, `Vfx` and `Vfy` should be updated to `self.Vx` and `self.Vy`.

Also, it's a good idea to indicate which particle it is in the local variables, eg `V1_x_initial`, `V2_x_initial`, etc.

Comment: Logically, I thought that when particle A and particle B collide, they would both run their update function to work out their final velocities so why have particle A work out the velocity of particle B as well?

Comment: Because in that case, when it's the other particles turn, ths particle' s velocity would already be its post-collision update velocity

Comment: Idk how Sprite manages this but you may need to check and skip pairs that have already been processed in each update. I don't see the position of the other particle updated neither in your code - and you need to do that too.

Comment: That is a really good point actually because one particle is updated and then another so the initial velocities may not be the same. In this case, could I use multiprocessing so that each particle is updated at the same time?

Comment: Oh you absolute legend xcmkz! I have added those two lines of code and now all the glitches are gone! Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help. There's no need for parallelism here (parallelism in computing is different from things happening physically at the same time anyway). In numerical simulations time is discrete. You update the system when you update all elements exactly once. Within this step, the entire system is considered to be at the same time.

Comment: You just need to be very careful and make sure each element is updated once and once only. Intermediate variables may be helpful in more complex cases (more complex coupling for example) - you can store tentative "final" values in a temp var and update all elements together at the end when there's no more computation to be done.